# Use fileshare as a specific user

Tags: windows, network-share, windows-10

The problem I have is that I have an VM with VMWare WorkStation (Windows 10) used for develop desktop software. It is not on a domain as we copy it to developers.
So a named user Developer is autologged in to windows.

I want to access a fileshare \testappserv in our network. This is not permitted. This works fine in another VM with Windows 7.

Now in the eventlog we saw this:

```
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.
Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  Guest
Source Workstation: DESKTOP-JJPVFK3
Error Code: 0x0
An account was logged off.
Subject:
    Security ID:        TESTAPPSERV\Guest
    Account Name:       Guest
    Account Domain:     TESTAPPSERV
    Logon ID:       0x15d4355
Logon Type:         3
This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.
```

So it try to use the fileshare as guest. Of course that fails.
How can I access this fileshare as a specific user with more permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem

search > gpedit.msc

Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Network>Lanman Workstation

open "Enable insecure guest logons" and choose Enabled.